# MySQL: AND operator doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have chat database contains from three table (users,message,message_recipient)
and their relations here :
[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIilO.png)
the content of table is :

tabel users:

`us_id  username  password
 1      user1     pass1
 2      user2     pass2
 3      user3     pass3`

table mesasage

```
id  msg_body   create_date  creator_id
1   "Hi user2" ---------      1
2   "Hi user3  ---------      1
```

table message_recipient

```
id  repient_id  message_id is_read
1   2           1          0
2   3           2          0
```

**my problem is when select the messages that user1 send to user2 the AND operator not working or there is bug with AND**
the SQL Query :

```
SELECT message.id, message.msg_body,message.creator_id,message_recipient.recipient_id
FROM message,message_recipient
WHERE message.creator_id='1' AND message_recipient.recipient_id='2'
```

the output is:

```
id msg_body    creator_id    recipient_id
1  "Hi user2"  1             2
2  "Hi user3"  1             2
```

Comment: what do you expect? it is working as coded

Comment: @Mena Armanyous can you try my below answer and let me know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN` to do that:-

```
SELECT message.id, message.msg_body,message.creator_id,message_recipient.recipient_id
FROM message JOIN message_recipient ON message.id = message_recipient.message_id
WHERE message.creator_id='1' AND message_recipient.recipient_id='2'
```

Note:- When you are trying to get data from two or more tables then you need to use different types of `Joins`.

Reference:- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @JYoThI  no, until you use join you can't fetch data from two different tables if they are interlinked (based on condition).

Comment: tanqqq so much @AlivetoDie

Comment: @JYoThI  you'r welcome. (BTW you can check it by creating all the tables given by OP in question, it will not take much time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join them on message id. Try this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.msg_body, m.creator_id, mr.recipient_id
FROM message m 
JOIN message_recipient mr on m.id=mr.id
WHERE m.creator_id='1' AND mr.recipient_id='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this in where clause `message.id = message_recipient.message_id` in your code and it's works

we can able to join multiple table using where clause .

```
SELECT message.id, 
message.msg_body,message.creator_id,message_recipient.recipi‌​ent_id FROM 
message,message_recipient WHERE message.id = message_recipient.message_id and 
message.creator_id='1' AND message_recipient.recipient_id='2'
```